# Получение name и label при помощи JDBC через openquery

Tags: java, база-данных, sql-server, jdbc, db2

Есть запрос:

```
    select 
         table1,
         table2 as [ФИО],
         table3 as [Должность],
    from
        openquery
            b8z44,
              'select...
```

При помощи JDBC получаются хэдеры таблицы.

```
        ResultSet rs = connect.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE).executeQuery();;

        for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            DataTable.headers.add(new UniversalHeader(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1), rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1), UniversalHeader.KEY_TYPE.NONE, UniversalHeader.FIELD_TYPE.convert(rs.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(i + 1))));
        }
```

И вывод:

```
Header names:
table1 ФИО Должность
=======================
Header labels:
table1 ФИО Должность
```

Я предполагал, что rs.getMetaData().getColumnName() будет возвращать системное имя колонки в базе данных, а  rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel() - алиас. Однако они возвращают одно и то же. Запрос делается через openquery через MS SQL к DB2. Есть ли возможность вытащить системные имена колонок как они есть, игнорируя `as [ФИО] и as [Должность]?

Итоговый вывод должен быть такой:
`

```
Header names:
table1 table2 table3 
=======================
Header labels:
table1 ФИО Должность
```

Comment: А если убрать алиасы столбцов с первого запроса?

Comment: Не, это не решение. Мне их надо выводить как хэдеры, но получать их надо по имени системной таблицы DB2

Comment: Я не понял, вы их получить смогли? Если да, то воспользуйтесь дальше динамическим запросом для подстановки полученных значений в заголовки

Comment: в случае с алиасами, получаются только алиасы, неважно по getName или по getLabel. Если алиас убрать, то получаются только значения. А надо чтобы и то, и другое